# openGL ES 2.0. image fit screen in landscape and portrait orientation Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-image

I start learning openGL ES 2.0. Now i can add texture to objects and create elementary figures(sphere, triangle, cube etc).
But now I have some problem. I have rectangle with texture. It is my target image. And now I want make this image fitted the drawing region in landscape and portrait orientation. Basically images are landscape oriented.
For exaple:
[image: for portarait orientation]
[image: for landscape orientation]

Screen must be without black lines near the borders of screen. When screen change they orientation - image must change size and fit screeen again.
I don't know how implement it on OpenGl on Android. what should I change? parameters of viewport or other parameters? and how i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want a projection that takes the screen size and orientation into account. For example:

```
float aspectRatio = width / (float) height;
orthoM(projectionMatrix, 0, -aspectRatio, aspectRatio, -1f, 1f, -1f, 1f);
```